# kubernetes upgrade failed due to resource already exists

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a kuberntes cluster I tried to do some changes in my configmap and then delete and redeploy my chary but I keep getting  when upgradeing

```
Release "test" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: release test failed: configmaps "test-configmap" already exists
```

however I verified before and it wasn't exist for sure is it means something wrong with my configmap what should I check?

Answer (score 0):

I add an extra file in my templates which not related to the chart I delete it and redeploy